# C++ return cannot convert from int to int&

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I have the following code:

```
ValueType& operator[](KeyType target) {
        Pair<KeyType, ValueType> * result = find(target);
        if (result != nullptr) {
            return result->getSecond();
        }
    }
```

I get this compile-time error: "return cannot convert from int to int&". I can get the it to compile by adding a const in front of the the method but then I can use the []operator to access elements only and not to change them. Another thing that I tried is to change the return type to ValueType&& but I do not really understand how that works. Still I cannot access and modify elements using the []operator. Normally this works for me but now I am using a template. Can that cause problems for me?

Comment: `getSecond()` seems to return an int by value. Returning a reference to a function local object does not make sense

Comment: "Normally this works for me but now I am using a template". --> No. It never works, nothing to do with template.

Comment: Just saw that I am saving it locally, my bad.

Comment: too many details missing, but what is the signature for `Pair::getSecond()` ?

Comment: It returns the ValueType variable (second) in the Pair. How can I get it to work then without running the find() locally here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to guess a little bit here but it seems like your `Pair` class is probably written like this:

```
template <typename First, typename Second>
class Pair {
 private:
  First first_;
  Second second_;
 public:
  // ...
  First getFirst() { return first_; }
  Second getSecond() { return second_; }
};
```

If first and second are not themselves reference types, then your `operator[]` would be binding a reference to a local (not great).

What you probably want in your `Pair` is to return references

```
template <typename First, typename Second>
class Pair {
 private:
  First first_;
  Second second_;
 public:
  // ...
  First& getFirst() { return first_; }
  Second& getSecond() { return second_; }

  // and const versions as well
  const First& getFirst() const { return first_; }
  const Second& getSecond() const { return second_; }
};
```

---

Why have the const versions? Because if you have a const `Pair` you still want to be able to look at its data I assume, consider a line like

```
const Pair<KeyType, ValueType> * result = find(target);
std::cout << result->getFirst() << '\n';
```

If you didn't have a const overload for `getFirst()` the above call would fail. This is relevant for you because most of the time you have `operator[]();` you want to also have `operator[]() const;` to go along with it.

If you look at the standard containers, you will see what I'm talking about. [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) for example.

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly now. I have one question though. Why do I need the const versions of the getters in the Pair and when are they called instead of the other 2.